# How can I implement C structs in Java? I know I am supposed to use classes, but rather I would like to ask if the following Java code is valid?

Tags: java, c, oop

Let's assume I want to define a circle in a coordinative plan. In C, I can do something like this:

```
struct point{
    int x;
    int y;
};
struct circle{
    struct point center; //this line in particular I am not sure how to implement
    int radius;
};
```

In java, I am trying the following...

```
public class Point{
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

```
public class Circle{
    Point center; //is this line correct? Or did I screw up?
    int radius;
}
```

If the above line is incorrect, could you please provide me with the correct code?

Comment: What did your compiler say when you tried it?

Comment: This is just some code, without any further context.  I don't know what you expect us to say about it.

Comment: Questions that ask "Is this correct" are unanswerable without more context.  What do you mean by "correct?"  Don't respond with things like "best practice;" that's the same thing.  Define what "correct" means to you.  If you're getting errors, state what they are.

Comment: Before Java 14, a class is **definitely** the closest analogue to a `struct`. **But**, as of Java 14, I would prefer a [record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/records.html). Trying to learn about one language (Java), by learning a second language (C) is a bad idea. In Java, there are default values and no uninitialized types. In your C code, you *might* have undefined behavior. And that's ***always*** fun!

Answer (score 1):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72519072/how-can-i-implement-c-structs-in-java-i-know-i-am-supposed-to-use-classes-but#comment128105013_72519072), comparing programming languages can be a problematic way to learn. In this case, C and Java are two different kinds of languages. Java is [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), c is not. So Java has a sophisticated [type system](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) based on classes, with no analog in C.

In Java you can indeed define a class as you showed for `Point`. But you are missing a constructor with parameters.

```java
public class Point{
    int x;
    int y;

    public Point ( final int x , final int y ) {
        this.x = x ; 
        this.y = y ;
    }

}
```

Instantiating calls the constructor, passing arguments.

```
Point p = new Point( 7 , 42 ) ;
```

If the main purpose of your class is to communicate data transparently and immutably, then define your class as a [record](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) in Java 16+.

```
public record Point ( int x , int y ) {}
```

The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`. But do not think of this as a mere `struct`. There is *much* more going on with a record. A record is still a class, in Java. For details, read the JEP 395 linked above.

Yes, you can use your defined class as the type of a member field of another class.

```
public record Circle ( Point center , int radius ) {}
```

In real work, I would add a constructor to perform null-checks and data validation. But we will ignore that here.

Instantiate.

```
Circle c = new Circle( new Point ( 7 , 42 ) , 5 ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( c ) ;
System.out.println ( c.center().y() ) ;
```

Comment: I strongly recommend `public record Circle ( Point center , int radius ) { public Circle { Objects.requireNonNull(center); } }` Besides that, keep in mind that when the record component is named `center`, you have to access it using that name, instead of `point`. Further, the fields are `private`, so unless you’re inside the same top level class, you will have to use the accessor methods; the example should be `System.out.println(c.center().y());` instead of `System.out.println(c.point.y);`

Comment: This is already a decent answer. Can you please add the following detail? In C when you nest structs, they are embedded into the memory layout. So `sizeof(circle)` would be `3*sizeof(int)` (alignment/padding disregarded). But in Java the circle would translate to `sizeof(int)+sizeof(void*)`. So what you can do in C with structs is not possible in Java.